# converting a list of datums to strings in racket

Tags: racket

What would be the easiest way to convert `'(a b c)` to `("a" "b" "c")`? I'd like to use the `string-join` function but it only takes in a list of strings.

Comment: `(map symbol->string '(a b c))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(map symbol->string '(a b c))` as pointed out by @alexis-king.